# Can anyone help me with a "simple" way to wrap a mesh onto a rounded base mesh?

Tags: mesh

can anyone help me with a "simple" way to wrap a mesh onto a rounded base mesh? I already got it "snapping" to the body mesh, but now I also want to wrap/bend it around the body mesh.

The idea is that the pointy "Face" shape mesh is folded nicely onto "Body" and is shaped/bend nicely with all ends around the round body. And that the face mesh (with solidify modifier is just a bit "higher" then the body it self).

I've tried shrinkwrap modifier but that doesn't give me the proper outcome.
I've also tried custom bending and curves modifier but nothing really works well.
I've also tried Simple Deform modifier, and this also isn't working the way I want it.

Anyone has any suggestions? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something like this? https://i.imgur.com/AMiNoQw.png

Comment: Use a Surface Defrom with a subdivided plane as target and shnrikwrap this plane onto the body? Probably what kalaakaar suggests

Comment: @The Kalaakaar Thnx for replying! Yes your (@The Kalaakaar) example is exactly what I am trying to achieve.. How did yoy do this? Like Moonboots says or another way?

Comment: @moonboots 

And trying your Surface deform modifier way doesnt do anything to the face" cause I can't use it as a target in the Surface Deform modifier menu. Maybe cause my "face" mask is an imported SVG that I converted to a mesh and then cleaned the vertices? Thnx!

Comment: @LeeJungBaltus To be honest, I did absolutely nothing special. Just make sure that your modifiers are in the correct order. And make sure you have enough geometry (Subdivision will help). The order now will be, Subdivsion, ShrinkWrap and then finally solidify.

Comment: Thx again @TheKalaakaar. Ok what I did next is create a totally new project with a subdived (used the method after just creating the sphere, in the little menu in the bottom left and added more segments.. then shaded smooth). Then added a plane and used Right mouse button to subdivide that plane also.. Then I used Shrinkwrap and then solidify.. and now I've got this weird result :)

Must be a noob mistake somewhere? 

https://imgur.com/a/AD7iq12

Comment: Hello @Lee Jung Baltus please share your file so that we can give a try

Comment: Here you can download the Blender file (v3.6) 

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a350d38ff8a42e744c940173d2ed10f320231102094736/3400dd3ad1e95e6e44aedf38a72a352120231102094747/afbcbb

Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is not the way you shrink wrapped things. The problem is the Face-mask thingy doesn't exactly have the perfect/required geometry to get shrink wrapped.

To take care of the issue, simply make your Face-mask thingy like this:

[image]

And not like this:

[image]

The issue: The way you have currently made the Face-mask thingy, there is not a single place where the mesh can bend. In my version there are faces all over in the middle region as well. The edges of these faces are where the mesh will bend and wrap over the target mesh. Technically speaking, your face does actually have places to bend. This is because the face gets triangulated automatically. But since this triangulation is not in our control, as well as, the edges are just not enough whatsoever, the end result is a complete mess.

Comment: Thnx @The Kalaakaar! To be honest this theory was also what I was thinking. But can you tell how to get the mesh the same geometry as yours? This is what my process is, can you tell what to do next? Cause this is my process and it doesnt work at all..

1. import face thing SVG
2. convert svg to a mesh
4. clean messy mesh with Dissolve Faces (dit mode)
5. I try normal Subdivide (w right mouse button) nothing happens
6. I try to use Subdivision Surface Modifier and Blender takes a long time to load it and it looks frozen. After its done loading there are still no new geometry added.

Comment: @Lee Jung Baltus if you are working with an svg, convert it into a mesh and give it a Solidify modifier and a Remesh modifier set to Sharp mode. Increase the remesh level until it's similar to the shape. Then apply both modifiers. Then go into edit mode and make it flat again. You can select one face and Shift+G->Coplanar, then ctrl+I to invert the selection and delete the other faces

Comment: It's just a plane. I added two loop cuts. Horizontal and vertical. Then to avoid any asymmetries, I deleted the verts on the left side and used a mirror modifier. I added a subdivision surface modifier as well. Now, I selected the two vertices at the top, and in the side panel, set their Vertex Crease to 1. Then moved the vertices a bit to get the desired shape. Next, the shrink wrap and finally the solidify.

Comment: Thnx both of you guys. I tried your SVG way (Cornivius) But It didn't work.

And I will try your way (The Kalaakaar) of just recreating the face svg shape as a new plane. But do you might have a way of getting the same result done using an imported svg like in my workflow? Cause as a graphic designer I work alot with premade vector assets form Illustrator. And having to remake every shape in Blender will take too much time. And maybe my SVG to Blender workflow (like I stated above) isn't the right way of turning a svf into a proper clean mesh? Much appreciated.

Comment: @LeeJungBaltus You can use grid fill. Select the loop and Ctrl+F > Grid fill. But I have never used SVGs in my projects, so idk for sure if this will work.